# Proposed analysis of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have been practicing analyzing algorithms lately. I feel like I have a pretty good understanding of analyzing non-recursive algorithms but I am unsure, and have just begun to embark on a full understanding of recursive algorithm as well. Although, I have not had a formal check on my methods and if what I have been doing is indeed correct

Would it be too much to ask if someone could check a few algorithms that I have implemented and analyzed and see if my understanding is along the right lines or if I am completely off.

here:

1)

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < i*i; j++){
        if (j % i == 0) {
            for (k = 0; k < j; k++){
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My analysis of this one was O(n^5) due to:
Sum(i = 0 to n)[Sum(j = 0 to i^2)[Sum(k = 0 to j) of 1]]
which evaluated to:
(1/2)(n^5/5 + n^4/2 + n^3/3 - n/30) + (1/2)(n^3/3 + n^2/2 + n/6) + (1/2)(n^3/3 + n^2/2 + n/6) + n + 1.
Hence it is O(n^5)

Is this correct as an evaluation of the summations of the loops?

a triple summation. I have assumed that the if statement will always pass for worse case complexity. Is this a correct assumption for worst case?

2)

```
int tonyblair (int n, int a) {
    if (a < 12) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            System.out.println("*");
        }
        tonyblair(n-1, a);
    } else {
        for (int k = 0; k < 3000; k++){
            for (int j = 0; j < nk; j++){
                System.out.println("#");
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

My analysis of this algorithm is O(infinity) due to the infinite recursion in the if statement if it is assumed to be true, which would be the worst case. Although, for pure analysis, I analyzed if this were not true and the if statement would not run. I then got a complexity of O(nk) due to:

Sum(k = 0 to 3000)[Sum(j = 0 to nk) of 1]
which then evaluated to nk(3001) + 3001. Hence is O(nk), where k is not discarded due to it controlling the number of iterations of the loop.

Comment: You would probably get more answers if you sounded a bit less full of yourself. A simple way of understanding these things is to check the actual number of executions. Putting your theories to the test would spare you and your readers lengthy glosses on false assumptions.

Comment: Im not seeing how I am sounding full of myself, if you have not read my post! I am asking if my calculations are correct! Are you guys ful of yourselves or what, geez. Everytime I come on here for some help you guys are all A holes. like I mentioned. I HAVE NOT HAD A FORMAL CHECK ON WHAT I HAVE BEEN DOING. That is why I came here. If you are not going to help me, please just get off

Comment: Next time, Ill just go elsewhere since you guys are terrible at giving help.

Comment: @kuroineko OP probably didn't need the "it seems like I have a pretty good understanding" part, but you come off as just plain rude and judgmental.

Comment: @MillieSmith allright, let's put it on a cultural misunderstanding then.

Comment: Do you live in Japan @kuroineko. I'm genuinely curious now.

Comment: Much worse than that: in Paris, France. So you'll have to excuse my French...

Comment: @JamesCombs - for the problem #1, note that the inner loop over k is only executed when j % i = 0. Since loop over j goes up to i^2, condition j % i = 0 will be true i times, so inner loop will be executed i times, not i^2 times. So I think this code comes closer to O(n^3), not O(n^5)

Comment: It's actually n^4, but I don't have time to do a writeup tonight.

Comment: @JamesCombs I wrote up an answer down below. I hope you aren't too put off by the community. I think they were just annoyed that you said you were "pretty good". If all you do is ask the question, they can't complain.

Comment: Im sorry for making them get so angry at me, but to me it didn't sound like I was being arrogant. I just really meant it as in I feel confident on my answers and would like to see if others feel the same, or if I am just completely wrong. Thanks btw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Number 1**

I can't tell how you've derived your formula. Usually adding terms happens when there are multiple steps in an algorithm, such as precomputing data and then looking up values from the data. Instead, nested for loops implies multiplication. Also, the worst case is the best case for this snippet of code, because given a value of n, sum will be the same at the end.

To find the complexity, we want to find the number of times that the inner loop is evaluated. Summations are often easy to solve if they go from 1 to n, so I'm going to drop the 0s from them later on. If i is 0, the middle loop won't run, and if j is 0, the inner loop won't run. We can rewrite the code equivalently as:

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j < i*i; j++)
    {
        if (j % i == 0) 
        {
            for (k = 0; k < j; k++)
            {
                sum++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could make my life harder by forcing the outer loop to start at 2, but I'm not going to. The outer loop now runs from 1 to n-1. The middle loop runs based on the current value of i, so we need to do a summation:

[image]

The middle for loop always goes to (i^2 - 1), and j will only be divisible by i for a total of (i - 1) times (i, i*2, i*3, ..., i*(i-2), i*(i-1)). With this, we get:

[image]

The middle loop then executes j times. The j in our summation is not the same as the j in the code though. The j in the summation represents each time the middle loop executes. Each time the middle loop executes, the j in the code will be `(i * (number of executions so far)) = i * (the j in the summation)`. Therefore, we have:

[image]

We can move the i to in-between the two summations, as it is a constant for the inner summation. Then, the formula for the sum of 1 to n is well known: `n*(n+1)/2`. Because we are going to n - 1, we must subtract n out. This gives:

[image]

The summations for the sum of squares and the sum of cubes are also well known. Keeping in mind that we are only summing to n-1 in both cases, we must remember to subtract n^3 and n^2, respectively, and we get:

[image]

This is obviously n^4. If we solve it all the way, we get:

[image]

**Number 2**

For the last one, it is in fact O(infinity) if a < 12 because of the if statement. Well, technically everything is O(infinity), because Big-O only provides an upper bound on runtime. If a < 12, it is also omega(infinity) and theta(infinity). If only the else runs, then we have the summation from 1 to 2999 of i*n:

[image]

It's very important to notice that the summation from 1 to 2999 is a constant (it's 4498500). No matter how large a constant is, it's still a constant, and not dependent on n. We will end up throwing it out of the runtime calculations. Sometimes, when a theoretically fast algorithm has a large constant, it is practically slower than other algorithms that are theoretically slow. One example I can think of is [Chazelle's linear time triangulation algorithm](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/polygon-triang.pdf). No one has ever implemented it. In any case, we have 4498500 * n. This is theta(n):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort to give a complete answer. This was more than helpful. I was trying to understand how others were doing it, but as learning this on my own time, I was not completely understanding exactly how to do more complex dependent loops. I saw PLENTY of beginner basics but wasn't enough to help me out here.

Comment: You're welcome. A lot of the time, it's just summations etc... logs appear during certain operations, for instance with sorting (known to be nlogn using a comparison algorithm). Log can also appear with binary searches.

Comment: I don't want to make the answer confusing, but the code above can also be written as `for (j = i; j < i*i; j += i)`, and then you can remove the `if` statement.